# slow interactive response time

Tags: freebsd, vmware-esxi

VMWare ESXi4 with 2 VM's (FreeBSD-amd64).
When doing a reboot on one of the VM's, the reboot is done in normal speed, but after that, the interactive response time on the other gets very slow:
pressing return at the command prompt, takes serveral seconds to be exectuted. SSH-ing to the VM machine takes a long time before you are logged in. Only after 20 minutes or so, the situation is normalized.

What's the reason and how to remedy?

Answer (score 1):

Smells like memory exhaustion. How overcommited is the physical memory on the host?

Answer (score 0):

In `/boot/loader.conf`, try to add

```
kern.hz=50
```

and reboot.

You may find other tips (including the one above) [here](http://ivoras.sharanet.org/freebsd/vmware.html).